# Exporting 2 values with one input with html form

Tags: php, html, forms, post, input

I found a slider template which has two values (min, max). The slider visually works but i want to use it in a form (method="post"). Looks like this(screenshot):

[image: screenshot]

It is in my main page and i have to use the min-max values in search.php. The slider code is below.

I have two questions. Does it look good here? And what should i write in search.php to get the values?

```
<form id="search" action="search.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" >
    <input type="text" class="span2" value="" data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="1500" data-slider-step="5" data-slider-value="[290,1170]" id="sl2"><br />
    <b class="pull-left">0</b> <b class="pull-right">1500</b>
    </br>
    <a href="search.php" onClick="document.getElementById('search').submit()" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-search"></i><b>Търси</b></a>
</form>
```

Here is what i tried and failed in search.php:

```
<?php
$min = $_POST['sl2[1]'];
$max = $_POST['sl2[2]'];
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT!!!

the slider is from http://www.eyecon.ro/bootstrap-slider/. There was no button there. I added it.

Comment: Try to print_r($_POST) on your result page : the code you show is probably "before" the slider js activation. it probably generate something like <input type="hidden" name="min" />... and there is 3 ways to know that : print_r($_POST), read the doc, or look at HTML code generated (not CTRL+U, F12)

Comment: Tried now. Only "Array ( )" it says

Answer (score 2):

Your data located in attribute:

```
data-slider-value="[290,1170]"
```

You need to export this attribute via JS, because form won't pass this attribute to PHP.

Value can be splitted in JS via var.split() or on PHP side via explode()

Comment: just to try to look it is empty or not, i wrote $minml = $_POST['sl2']; in search.php. It says:"Notice: Undefined index: sl2"